# Fail to confirm user. 400 Bad Request - Invalid app key

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

im am experiencing problems with the email validation in the appcelerator platform. I have everything configured right and the email arrive in my inbox when a new user is created, but, for some reason, the link to activate the account returns: Fail to confirm user. 400 Bad Request - Invalid app key

I checked in the tiapp.xml and checked if the api keys are properly configured and everything is alright. I have no idea of how appcelerator generate this link to verify what happen. In my template uses the link below:

https://cloud.appcelerator.com/users/confirmation?key={{key}}&confirmation_token={{confirmation_token}}

What im doing wrong? =[

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the documentation is wrong. Only works if the link in the template is https://platform.appcelerator.com/#/users/confirmation/{{key}}/{{confirmation_token}}

Comment: Where did you spot this documentation bug? Could you fix it via the Wiki/PR or let me know so I can? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I've reported the issue for further verification.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue and can confirm the bug in the documentation. The correct url is indeed

```
https://platform.appcelerator.com/#/users/confirmation/{{key}}/{{confirmation_token}}
```

I'd like to add that there is probably a similar defect in the following documentation for password reset url:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/Users-method-request_reset_password

The documentation says the password reset url (if using Appcelerator instead of custom website) should be

```
https://dashboard.appcelerator.com/#/users/confirmation/{{key}}/{{confirmation_token}}
```

It seems wrong (copy-paste from email confirmation url perhaps).